# How to represent `self` url in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, hateoas

I want to add a link to a single resource representation which is an URL to itself, `self`. Like (taken from documentation):

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'track_listing')

{
    'album_name': 'The Eraser',
    'artist': 'Thom Yorke',
    'self': 'http://www.example.com/api/album/2/',
}
```

How should this be done?

Answer (score 4):

If you inherit `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` all you need to do is pass a `url` field to `fields`. See the docs here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/

Comment: `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` will cause all your related fields to be hyperlinked, which is not what he aims to do. He just wants link to add hyperlink to `self`.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, this solved my problem but if you have a better solution please post an answer:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import serializers

self_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_self')

def get_self(self, obj):
    request = self.context['request']
    return reverse('album-detail', kwargs={'id': obj.id}, request=request)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution,

in your view methods create serilizer object like this:

```
album = AlbumSerializer(data=data, {"request":request})
```

in your serilizer class override `to_representation` method (you can read about this method on [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = super().to_representation(obj)
        request = self.context["request"]
        return data
```

Comment: `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` will cause all related fields to be hyperlinked, which is not what he aims to do. He just wants link to add hyperlink to `self`.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/issues/241), you can just add 'url' in the list of fields.

Comment: I think that's only if you're using `django-rest-framework-json-api`. The django rest framework by itself doesn't do that by default. You have to make your serializer from HyperlinkedModelSerializer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little more context than you got in the other answers so far. The key is the `context` argument passed to the serializer constructor and the `'url'` in fields.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/

In your viewset:

```
class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Album.objects.all()
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(queryset, many=True, 
                                     context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In the serializer:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'track_listing', 'url')
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated above the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` will convert all your related fields and remove the ID of the resource as well. I use one of the following solutions, depending on the situation.

**Solution 1:** import api settings and add the url field:

For more details see [URL_FIELD_NAME](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#url_field_name).

```
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings

class AlbumSerializer(SelfFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'track_listing', api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME)
```

**Solution 2:** a simple mixin, which only works if default fields are used:

```
class SelfFieldMixin:
    """
    Adds the self link without converting all relations to HyperlinkedRelatedField
    """

    def get_default_field_names(self, declared_fields, model_info):
        """
        Return the default list of field names that will be used if the
        `Meta.fields` option is not specified.
        """
        default_fields = super().get_default_field_names(declared_fields, model_info)
        return [self.url_field_name, *default_fields]
```

And it can be used like

```
class AlbumSerializer(SelfFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

**NOTE:** It requires **Python 3** due to the `super()` call, the a mixin must be placed **before** any of the serializer classes!

**P.S.:** To achieve the required response in the question one must also set the [URL_FIELD_NAME](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#url_field_name) to `'self'`.

**Edit**: `get_default_field_names` must return a `list` object for `Meta.exclude` to work on `ModelSerializers`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HyperlinkedIdentityField` like so:

```
class ThingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = ['self_link', ...]

    self_link = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='thing-detail')
```

You need to have your routes named appropriately but the Default routers do so automatically (documented [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)).

As others have pointed out the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` also works. This is because it uses this field automatically. See [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/#hyperlinking-our-api).